# Windows Phone 8.1 with Bing maps returns Access violation

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, bing-maps

I am trying to bind a collections of points to the Bing map control and everything works great for the first time (when I am opening the view with this map for the first time) but every another attempt end up with this pure message in the output window:

```
The program 'xxx' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.
```

There is no exceptions, nothing only this message. What I have tried so far is [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsapps/en-us/fde433e8-87f8-4005-ac81-01b12e016986/debugging-access-violation-exceptions) article from MSDN but without success. I have also tried to run the code on the UI thread but it didn't help.

In the ViewModel I am doing this:

```
Issues.Completed += () =>
        {
            Locations = new ObservableCollection<MapItemViewModel>();
            foreach (var issueLto in Issues.Result)
            {
                Locations.Add(new MapItemViewModel
                {
                    Name = issueLto.Title,
                    Location = new MapPointViewModel
                    {
                        Longitude = issueLto.Longitude,
                        Latitude = issueLto.Latitude
                    }
                });
            }

            MapCenter = Issues.Result.Select(c => new MapCenterViewModel
            {
                Location = new MapPointViewModel
                {
                    Latitude = c.Latitude,
                    Longitude = c.Longitude
                }
            }).FirstOrDefault();
        };
```

And the XAML:

```
<maps:MapControl
              MapServiceToken="{StaticResource BingServiceToken}"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              Center="{Binding MapCenter.Location, Converter={StaticResource MapCoordinatesConverter}}">
                <maps:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}">
                    <maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding Location, Converter={StaticResource MapCoordinatesConverter}}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Black"/>
                                <Image Source="../../Assets/mappin.png" Height="25"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </maps:MapItemsControl>
            </maps:MapControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe because you can't bind the center property of the Map Control, there's a workaround using Behavior SDK, please read this article:
http://dreamteam-mobile.com/blog/2012/10/better-bing-maps-sdk-for-metro-apps-winrt-windows8-en/

in MSDN, this is helpful:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/436fc737-19c8-4832-a1c4-368f88063616/anyway-to-make-a-binding?forum=bingmapswindows8

Comment: Hi, I also thought about this issue but this strange behavior is related to `Locations` collection, because when I comment it and the only map center is calculated application is not crashing.